# Get multiple user with similar names from Active Directory using C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I need to display a list of users (in autocomplete) with similar names from the AD. For example, if I search Arthur and there are 2 people with same name (first name or last name), I should display both the names in the autocomplete. I tried to get the names but it is taking around 2-4 minutes to get the names. I am using the following code:

```
        string[] domainNames = new string[] { "domain1", "domain2" };
        List<string> userNames = new List<string>();
        string user = string.Empty;

        foreach (string domain in domainNames)
        {
            using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
            {
                GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "Domain Users");
                if (group != null)
                {
                    foreach (Principal p in group.GetMembers(false))
                    {
                        if (p.Name.ToLower().Contains(key.ToLower()))
                        {
                            if (!userNames.Contains(p.Name))
                                userNames.Add(p.Name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Any way I can speed up the process? I am already using ajax call.

Comment: I don't think you can expect to get fast enough response from the AD for a query to be used for auto-complete. So you'll have to get a list of _all_ AD entries ahead of time and save them in a List<> or something similar so you can do a fast lookup as the user is typing.

Comment: Another idea: I'm not familiar with the PrincipalContext object or how it is used to get AD entries. The program I've created to read from the AD is based on LDAP. Here's the sample that got me started: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4237/Querying-Active-Directory-using-NET-classes-and-LD But note a comment by a certain RenniePet back in 2010.

Comment: I found the below site very useful for making queries: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
        DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher();
        ds.SearchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain, domain + @"\" + userName, password);
        ds.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(cn=*" + key + "*))";
        ds.PropertyNamesOnly = true;
        ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");
        ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");

        foreach (SearchResult searchResults in ds.FindAll())
        {
            foreach (string propertyName in searchResults.Properties.PropertyNames)
            {
                foreach (Object retEntry in searchResults.Properties[propertyName])
                {
                    var user = retEntry.ToString().Split('/').Where(x => x.Contains("CN")).Select(y => y).FirstOrDefault().Split(',').Where(z => z.Contains("CN")).Select(c => c).FirstOrDefault().Split(',').FirstOrDefault().Split('=')[1];
                    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user))
                        userNames.Add(user);
                }
            }
        }
```

Reduced to 30-40 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The `cn=` filter isn't really valid - there's nothing guaranteeing that format. Instead, look up Ambigous Name Resolution - it's designed for this: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22653.active-directory-ambiguous-name-resolution.aspx.